# change notify url for recuring payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a default notify URL for recurring payments,
Problem is that now i have to change it to a different one .

Is it possible to go back to all the recurring IPN's and change the address ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, but you could forward the data from the current IPN listener URL to a new one.  Just POST the data the original one receives to the new one.